# NodeJS : Async Await inside class

Tags: node.js

I have one scenario that i have one method  inside class so that i can access this method using object in other module. I know how to use asyn await without using class, but when i use async await inside class evenif i have asyn function it gives me error below is my code.

```
    class BatchModel {
        async getBatches(req) { 
         let response = await this.ProcessBatch()
         return response;
          }
          ProcessBatch() {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(()=>{
             resolve('a')
             },5000)
           })
          }
    }
module.exports = BatchModel
```

I thorows me error like

```
await this.ProcessBatch();
^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Comment: It will work fine, Which version of Node.js your using

Comment: i am using v8.12.0

Comment: Try updated your node version, https://repl.it/repls/WorrisomeBlondFirmware

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error, this is working fine